# How do I upsample a mapping grid?

Tags: matlab, grid, mapping

Say I have a grid given by X and Y from `meshgrid`. X denotes the columns and Y denotes the rows. I have a dense mapping between

```
[X(i,j),Y(i,j)] ---> [A(i,j),B(i,j)]
```

Unfortunately this grid X belongs to an image which is **[270,480]**. I wish to up-sample this mapping into say **[1080,1920]**.

What technique can I use? Can you provide any suggestions?

Comment: interpolation (`interp2`)?

Comment: See, that's what I don't understand @Dan. If I had an image and wanted to upsample it, sure I could go it. But these are grid points mapping to other grid points. It doesn't matter which I image I use, I want the grid mapping to remain the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking then. Exactly what end result do you want? If you want to upsample an image from 270x480 to 1080x1920 then `interp2` is the function for you. meshgrid is really just there to help you plot but there is no reason why you can use `interp2` on both your `meshgrid` outputs (i.e. `X` and `Y`), and on your image

Comment: interp2 can be used when grid points from image 1 are mapped to some color value. So say I have 270X480 worth of grid points with some color value, I can perform interpolation to 1080X1920.


In my case, Grid points don't point to a color, they point to OTHER grid locations in a DIFFERENT image. Hence, if say [10,10] was mapped to [12,12], then [100,100] should map to say [~120,~130]. I figured there is no straight forward way to go about this.

Comment: Is it an arbitrary mapping? Or a just an upscaling? You might be able to apply an affine transformation if it is the latter. Otherwise I once did something similar by performing a delaunay triangulation on the first set of vectors and then interpolating based on that triangulation...